# active class menu item in angularjs for routeparam path

Tags: angularjs

isActive to test for routeparam path like: angularjs/app/index.php#/pages-editmenus/36

my index.php

```
<li ng-class="{ active  : isActive('/pages-menus') || isActive('/pages-addmenus') || isActive('/pages-editmenus/{{lpath}}')}"><a href="#pages-menus"> Menus</a></li>
```

where lpath is $routescope variable in controller

```
$rootScope.lpath = $routeParams.id;
```

even for id 36 index.php replace like:

```
<li ng-class="{ active  : isActive('/pages-menus') || isActive('/pages-addmenus') || isActive('/pages-editmenus/36')}"><a href="#pages-menus"> Menus</a></li>
```

but it did n't add class means condition is false.
When I try with a static value (ex: 36) instead of `lpath` it's works fine. 
so what could be wrint here?

Answer (score 0):

You put your variable in `$rootScope`, you can't use it like this in your page.

I think in your case the best option would be to move it to `$scope`:

```
$scope.lpath = $routeParams.id;
```

---

Otherwise, you can affect `$rootScope.lpath` to your scope:

```
$scope.lpath = $rootScope.lpath;
```

I guess `isActive('/pages-editmenus/{{$rootScope.lpath}}')` should works as well, but I didn't tried. 
*I prefer [avoiding using `$rootScope`](http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/learn-how-to-use-scopes-properly-in-angularjs/).*